# I want to remove the tuples and ' ' from a list. I am working on django project

Tags: python, django

```
taluka=[('sirur',),('jath',),('mauli',)]    
queryset = data.objects.values_list("taluka").distinct()
queryset = [item[0] for item in queryset]
print(queryset)  // sirur,jath,mauli,etc
Taluka=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data.objects.values_list("taluka").distinct(),)
print(Taluka) // ('sirur',),('jath',),('mauli',)
```

I want the name of talukas to be printed as sirur,jath,mauli

Comment: You seem to have already figured it out for `queryset`…!?

Comment: Also you seem to be passing the result of `values_list` to `ModelChoiceField`? Why do you do this? `ModelChoiceField` takes a queryset (and not a list of choices) and internally handles getting the pk and the display value. If your purpose is to simply specify the choices for the `ModelChoiceField` don't go for list comprehensions or evaluate the data, just pass the queryset to the field `forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data.objects.all()`

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: You can use the join function to convert the tuples inside the list into strings and then converting the list of strings into a comma separated string again using the join function.

```
taluka=[('sirur',),('jath',),('mauli',)]   
taluka = ",".join(["".join(t) for t in taluka])
print(taluka)
```

Solution 2: Adding to the answer from [LOCKhart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20114610/lockhart), you can use list comprehension to convert the data into a list of strings and use the join function on it to convert it into a comma separated string.

```
taluka=[('sirur',),('jath',),('mauli',)]   
taluka = ",".join([i[0] for i in taluka])
print(taluka)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension

```
taluka = [i[0] for i in taluka]
```

Comment: Funny no-one should address *remove […] ' ' from a list*.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.values_list("taluka", flat=True)` to get a flat list of a single field without useless 1-tuples. You should get `['sirur', 'jath', 'mauli']`

Otherwise, list comprehensions are the way to go, as per LOCKhart's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
queryset = list(data.objects.values_list("taluka", flat=True).distinct())
```

do this and good to go